# PHP Matching number of occurrences

Tags: php

I have this PHP string :

```
$range = "['2018-03-17','2018-03-19','2018-03-18','2018-03-18']";
```

I'm wanting to loop through the entire string, and do something like..

```
if day == "Saturday" || day == "Sunday" and only one occurrence of this in string then { // Do something } else { // Do something else }
```

I've explored preg_match_all with a regex [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} but I can't get my head around it, any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You don't need a regex for this. Check [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php).

Comment: I don't think this is an array, its a string resembling an array, though you can better parse this string into an array, then convert each date to a date object and count them.

Comment: "loop through the entire string" is pretty vague, i guess it's not char by char, you should add your code here. You also should precise what is "this" in "occurrence of this in string", we assume it's a date string, but we shouldn't have to assume

Comment: Is `$range` a string or array?

Comment: It clearly says in the post, "I have this PHP String", it is a string.

Comment: Also I have no issues converting the string objects to a date objects if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
    <?php
    $range_string = '["2018-03-17","2018-03-19","2018-03-18","2018-03-18"]';
    $range = json_decode($range_string);

    foreach($range as $date){
     $nameOfDay = date('l', strtotime($date));
     if (($nameOfDay == 'Saturday' || $nameOfDay =='Sunday') && count(array_keys($range, $date)) == 1) 
     {
        echo "$nameOfDay exits only once on $date"."<br/>";
     }else{
        echo "$nameOfDay exits multiple time on $date"."<br/>";
     }
}
    ?>
```

**Output**

```
Saturday exits only once on 2018-03-17
Monday exits multiple time on 2018-03-19
Sunday exits multiple time on 2018-03-18
Sunday exits multiple time on 2018-03-18
```

Demo : 
https://eval.in/970622

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
 if (day == "Saturday" || day == "Sunday" && (substr_count($range,"2018-03-18")) == 1 ){ 
// Do something 
} else { 
// Do something else 
}
```

substr_count($range,"2018-03-18") will return 2 here. substr_count return the number of occurrence of a sub string in main string.

Hope it helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Should that be `$day`? also you are probably missing brackets round the first part of the condition.

Comment: This is just an overview of answer and Please neglect the syntax errors as I have not tested this. Although it just gives the brief idea of how it can be achieved. Kudos

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to decode your string to array:

```
$range = json_decode('["2018-03-17","2018-03-19","2018-03-18","2018-03-18"]');
```

And then loop:

```
$rangeCount = array_count_values($range);
forearch ($range as $d) {
    $date = new DateTime($d);
    $weekDay = (int) $date->format('N');
    $found = $rangeCount[$d];

    if ($weekDay === 6 || $weekDay === 7 && $found === 1) {
        // here is your code
    }
}
```

I haven't tested the code.